# SIGABRT crash on the first line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, sigabrt

I have an iOS app which was running fine until yesterday and suddenly started to crash with `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` at this point:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Having no idea of the cause I typed `bt` in the debugging console and got this:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xda342, 0x0000000194637270 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000194637270 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001946d5170 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 112
    frame #2: 0x00000001945aeb18 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 112
    frame #3: 0x000000018badf2ec GraphicsServices`_GSRegisterPurpleNamedPortInPrivateNamespace + 424
    frame #4: 0x000000018bade1d4 GraphicsServices`_GSEventInitializeApp + 140
    frame #5: 0x0000000186c86c38 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 712
  * frame #6: 0x00000001000592f0 TheApp`main + 164 at AppDelegate.swift:13
    frame #7: 0x000000019451ea08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
(lldb)
```

Browsing the net for similar issues I have read it may be due to some problems related to the StoryBoard, but since I am doing everything programmatically I have some doubts that it applies to my case. I have also tried to use an exception break point just in case, but with no success.

I have even remade the project, the problem is still there. It seems something goes wrong even before my code starts to execute. I wonder what I can check.

Anyway if someone can give me a hint on what may be the issue, or on how to further investigate, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding an exception breakpoint, or enabling zombies on your scheme?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I tried to use an exception break point, but with no success. It actually doesn't look like there is an exception.

Comment: And I think zombies exist only in objectiv-C, I am using Swift.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I can think of...

Comment: There must be something you changed since yesterday... If not, perhaps something broke in your IDE. Do other apps run OK?

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway. Other apps run OK. The problem is exactly to find out what has changed. On a step by step base all went well.
I may have done something wrong with the effects appearing only later.

Comment: I googled that `_GSRegisterPurpleNamedPortInPrivateNamespace ` in your console, but all results are related to keyboard extensions. Also, I think a zombie is basically when you try to access a deallocated object. I think it should be possible to recreate such runtime error using unsafe (unowned) references, even in swift.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85380/discussion-between-michel-and-nicolasmiari).

Comment: The only reason that function `abort()`s is if you have a zombie process still hung in the debugger somewhere.  Just restart the simulator.